# trying to set "list-style:;" css property to none;

Tags: css

I am working on this web, www.manchadesign.com, It´s built on wordpress using a themeforest template. I am used to code html and css, but this simple problem is driving me crazy.

I want to erase the disc on the list of the sub-menu, so I set this propoerty on css:

```
#access ul li {
    list-style:none!important;
    list-style-type:none!important;
    list-style-position:outside;
}
```

Besides of this I´ve applied comments on all properties of the css that previously add list-style to the template, so that rule that I´ve code It´s supose to be the only one afecting <.li> elements with the property list-style.

But in the end its not working, and I have no idea how to make that list-style:disc; disapear...

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong...?
Any possible different solutions...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not list style that is showing in your submenu its actually a pseudo class and this property adding dot with 'content' before every submenu.

Locate this property

```
#access ul li li a:before {content: "·";}
```

and replace this with

```
#access ul li li a:before {content: "";}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is best to apply `list-style` to the list and not the list items.

```
#access ul{
    list-style: none;
}
```

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-list-style) is the W3C reference

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're applying the list styles to the list *item* (`li`) instead f the list itself (`ul`).

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwcoffey/7YQy9/

Or change your code to:

```
#access ul { list-style:none!important; list-style-type:none!important; list-style-position:outside; }
```